# Handeling with nested multiple array in PHP (foreach)

Tags: php

I am trying to handle a situation with a nested multiple array that is received in `PHP` by `$_POST` from `Javascript-Jquery` (as Object not as Json)

. The nested Object looks like this:

```
{
   "Videotheck":{
      {
         "Category":"Comedy",
         "Title_Liste":[
            {
               "Title":"Millers",
               "Year":"2014"
            },
            {
               "Title":"Yogi",
               "Year":"2012"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Category":"Action",
         "Title_Liste":[
            {
               "Title":"Rodulf",
               "Year":"2014"
            },
            {
               "Title":"Matrix",
               "Year":"2000"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

And now the information in this Object need to be splited. For example the title list of each category should be stored in a var

```
$comedy_title_liste = [];
$action_title_liste = [];
```

I tryed this:

```
if($_POST){
$arr1 = $_POST['Videotheck'];
foreach($arr1 as $vtk){
    foreach($vtk as $data => $v){
        foreach($v as $key => $value){
          foreach($value as $k => $info){
              echo $k.' '. $info;
           }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Like this I can get only all title list from all categories, but is necessary to get for each category the list of titles separeted. I don't know really how to handle the situation.

Well this is what I have. I guest that there is something not correct.

Comment: What is inside `$arr1` php array or ? can you attach to your question result of `var_dump($arr1);` ?

Comment: is $arr1 supposed to be in the $_POST variable? You sure you dont want $_POST["arr1"] instead of $arr1?

Comment: Yes I will edit again the question because I forgot one information. THX!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "not json_decode" in the subject line? Because the json_decode function is exactly what you need to turn that data into a PHP array.

Comment: I mean, this is a Object not a Json, for that reason I think I don't need a json_decode. The object is send it by Javascript to PHP as Object and not as Json. But if you have another opinion, I am glad to hear

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% exact but you can give a try  :

```
$result = array();
$parent = $_POST['Videotheck'];

   foreach($parent as $key=> $child) { 
      $result[$child['Category']."_title_liste"] = array();
      foreach($child['Title_Liste'] as $cKey => $val) {
      $result[$child['Category']."_title_liste"][] = $val['Title'];
    }
 }
```